# HTML Form - How to send value to URL without key

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to send value of < input type="text"> to the URL without the key, which is  < input name="q">

With the below code, the  calls "http://localhost/Products/?q=XXXX". Instead, I want to see "http://localhost/Products/XXXXX"

```
<form method="get" class="search" action="/Products/">
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Please enter the name of the product that you want to find">
    <button type="submit" aria-label="Search"><i class="header-icon_search_custom"></i></button>
</form>
```

How can I achieve the URL that I described above?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it by just using the default submit behavior. According https://www.w3.org `GET` -

> With the HTTP "get" method, the form data set is appended to the URI specified by the action attribute (with a question-mark ("?") as separator) and this new URI is sent to the processing agent.

You can can use JavaScript over the form submit to get the desired request like: http://localhost/Products/XXXXX

Comment: How can I get the desired request with Javascript? Any idea?

Comment: You have an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186197/javascript-send-form-with-get-method